# ios- Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content? admob

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect

While submitting an app on itunes connect that has admob integrated, what should be the value for the checkbox "Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is **No**, don't check it, while you have to check that your app is Using IDFA and under that make sure that "Serve advertisements within the app" is checked.

Comment: I ended up answering NO and checking the first and third checkboxes for using IDFA, and that passed the app review process.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) how much time did the review take ?

Comment: Took only one day surprisingly. Usually takes about a week.

Comment: @user648931 I can not see option for third party content. I guess I have accepted it as Yes for the first time.