# Advertisement Identifier iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, idfa

I use iAd and AdMob banners for my app but also Chartboost interstitial image ads. For the IDFA question I have the following choices:

**1)Serve advertisements within the app**

**2)Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement**

**3)Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement**

I know to choose 1 for sure, but what about the others? What does 2 and 3 even mean, how do I know if I need to check them as well?

Comment: I had the same question. See this, it worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261926/ios-does-your-app-contain-display-or-access-third-party-content-admob/31262006?noredirect=1#comment50614027_31262006